# MatLab - Finding root of f(x) = x - tan(x) with bisection method

Tags: matlab, bisection

I have written a code for the bisection algorithm in MatLab.  I have based this on the pseudocode given in my textbook.  The algorithm has worked just fine on all my problems so far, but when I'm asked to find a root of f(x) = x - tan(x) on the interval [1,2] I have some troubles.  My code is as follows:

```
function x = bisection(a,b,M)
f = @(x) x - tan(x);
u = f(a);
v = f(b);
e = b-a;
x = [a, b, u, v]
if (u > 0 && v > 0) || (u < 0 && v < 0)
    return;
end;
for k = 1:M
    e = e/2;
    c = a + e;
    w = f(c);
    x = [k, c, w, e]
    if (abs(e) < 10^(-5) || abs(w) < eps)
        return;
    end
    if (w < 0 && u > 0) || (w > 0 && u < 0)
        b = c;
        v = w;
    else
        a = c;
        u = w;
    end
end
```

If I run this algorithm on the interval [1,2] with, say, 15 iterations, my final answer is:

```
x =

  1.0e+004 *

    0.0015    0.0002   -3.8367    0.0000
```

which is obviously way off as I wish to get f(c) = 0 (the third entry in the vector above).

If someone can give me any help/tips on how to improve my result, I would greatly appreciate it.  I am very new to MatLab, so treat me as a novice :).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's have a look at the sequence of `c` which is generated by the bisection method:

```
c =  1.5000
c =  1.7500
c =  1.6250
c =  1.5625
c =  1.5938
c =  1.5781
c =  1.5703
c =  1.5742
c =  1.5723
c =  1.5713
c =  1.5708
c =  1.5706
c =  1.5707
c =  1.5707
c =  1.5708
```

You can see that it converges to `pi/2`. The `tan()` has a singularity at this point and so does `x - tan(x)`. The bisection method converges to this singularity as is also stated [here](http://help.derivativepricing.com/1542.htm), for example. This is why the function value at `f(c)` is not close to zero. In fact it should go to (plus/minus) infinity.

**Other suggestions:**

I like your bisection method. To make it usable in a more general fashion, you could incorporate these changes:

- Make the variable `f` a function parameter. Then you can use your method with different
  functions without having to re-write it.
- The very first time you assign `x = [a, b, u, v]` but later on `x(1)` is the number of
  iterations. I would make this more consistent.
- You can easily test if `f(a)` and `f(b)` have different signs by looking at the sign of
  the product `p = f(a)*f(b)`. For `p > 0` the signs are equal and there is no root,
  for `p < 0` the signs differ and for `p == 0` either `f(a)` or `f(b)` is zero and you
  already have found the root.

Comment: Thanks a lot for you input and suggestions for improvement!  Really appreciate it - especially also the link which explains that the bisection method will converge to the singularity.  The reason I wrote the method like I did, and not with the product f(a)*f(b) as you suggest is that my book writes "it is better to determine whether the function changes sign over the interval using sign(w) ≠ sign(u), rather than u*w < 0, since the latter requires an unneccessary multiplication and could cause an underflow or overflow".

Comment: I agree, avoiding overflows and underflows is certainly an issue.